# Why enumeration cannot be a template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enum-class

`enumeration cannot be a template` is the error given when I try to compile with [BCC64](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/BCC64.EXE,_the_C++_64-bit_Windows_Compiler) (based on Clang) the following code:

```
template <typename T> enum class fooEnum : T
{
    a,b,c,d,e
};
```

At first, I was thinking that this explicit prohibition was due to the `enum` underlying type limitations, if the enum underlying type could be templated, then it could lead to ill-formed enums, but when we try this:

```
template <typename A> struct fooClass
{
    enum class fooEnum : A
    {
        a,b,c,d,e
    };
};
```

It compiles without problem as long as the `A` type follows the same limitations as the enum underlying types, you know, the expression that defines the value of an enumeration:

- Shall be an integer constant large enough to fit all the values of the enum
- Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char` or a `signed`/`unsigned` integer type.

If we do not not follow this rules, (with an in-class or a global enum) another specific error shows up, as expected:

```
enum class fooEnum : fooClass
{
    a,b,c,d,e
};
```

> non-integral type 'fooClass' is an invalid underlying type

So, that's why I'm wondering why is explicitly forbidden to create a template enum even when there is already a control over the underlying type. Where on the standard is mentioned this prohibition?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: There are only class and function templates in C++11. (C++14 is going to change that). A scoped enumeration is *not* a class, despite being declared with the `class` keyword.

Comment: @n.m. I know about the template variables of C++14, and I also know that the strong enums aren't classes. But the fact is that I don't know why the strong enums cannot template their underlying type, what logic (or illogic) reason is behind that explicit prohibition.

Comment: There's no good justification. The standsrd says so, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition [C++ standard 14.1], or by being outside of the definition,

> A template defines a family of classes or functions or an alias for a
>   family of types.

An enum is neither of these, so it cannot be a template.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the problem out by declaring the enum inside a class (containing only that).

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct myEnum
{
    enum Values
    {
        a=0, b=1,c=2
    };
};

int main() {
    myEnum<int> abc;
    cout<<abc.Values::a<< abc.Values::b<<abc.Values::c;
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 012

Tested with http://ideone.com/

Comment: You forget to make the enum a enum class ;)